# Listview with custom adapter shows repeating grid items if adapter used from Fragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, gridview, xamarin

It's Xamarin.Android via C#.

The problem is custom adapter shows too many items in ListView if adapter was used from Fragment code. If I'll use it from MainActivity it will work fine.

I Need to show dynamic custom info inside ListView element which is located in Tab (**Fragment**). Each row of ListView should contain dynamic quantity of text boxes one by one in one row. For this purpose custom **adapter generates GridLayout** with **TextView** elements. Quantity of rows also is dynamic, that's why **List<>** was used. I tried to simplify my code as much as possible. In real life Data class is more complicated, a lot of Tabs used, etc.

Input:
1. **Simple Class for some data**

```
public class MyData
{
    internal int ID;
    internal string Nick;

    public MyData(int _id, string _nick)
    {
        ID = _id;
        Nick = _nick;
    }
}
```

2. **Tab1.axml** is layout for our Tab we need to show. It contains only ListView element where Adapter should place data

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView1" />
```

3. **Grid.axml** is layout which will represent every single line for ListView. It will contain dynamic quantity of TextView elements inside of GridView

```
<GridLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
p1:minWidth="25px"
p1:minHeight="25px"
p1:layout_width="match_parent"
p1:layout_height="match_parent"
p1:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
p1:columnCount="2" />
```

4. **Main.axml** is main layout which contains Tabs (only 1 for this example). fragmentContainer is our container for Tab. listViewMain is listview to check if Adapter works properly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<FrameLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" />
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listViewMain" />
```

5. **MainActivity.cs** contains all the code

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        //creating one main tab
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        AddTab("Tab 1", new SampleTabFragment1());

        /* //to test if Adapter works properly From MainActivtity instead of Fragment
        List<MyData> listOfData = new List<MyData>();
        MyData item = new MyData(1, "Nick#1");
        listOfData.Add(item);

        item = new MyData(2, "Nick#2");
        listOfData.Add(item);

        ListView table = this.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewMain);
        table.Adapter = new MyDataAdapter(this, listOfData);*/
    }
```

Standard function for creating Tab:

```
void AddTab(string tabText, Fragment view)
    {
        var tab = this.ActionBar.NewTab();
        tab.SetText(tabText);

        // must set event handler before adding Tab
        tab.TabSelected += delegate (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
        {
            var fragment = this.FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer);
            if (fragment != null)
                e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(fragment);
            e.FragmentTransaction.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, view);
        };
        tab.TabUnselected += delegate (object sender, ActionBar.TabEventArgs e)
        {
            e.FragmentTransaction.Remove(view);
        };

        this.ActionBar.AddTab(tab);
    }
```

Fragment for Tab where we bind custom adapter to listview:

```
class SampleTabFragment1 : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnDestroyView()
        {
            base.OnDestroyView();
        }            
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Tab1, container, false);

            //Creating our data
            List <MyData> listOfData = new List<MyData>();                
            MyData item = new MyData(1, "Nick#1");
            listOfData.Add(item);

            item = new MyData(2, "Nick#2");
            listOfData.Add(item);

            //Find listview from Tab1.axml which is actually our Tab Fragment
            ListView table = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
            //Binding listview with custom adapter
            table.Adapter = new MyDataAdapter(this.Activity, listOfData);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Finally, adapter for our custom data:

```
public class MyDataAdapter : BaseAdapter<MyData>
    {
        Activity context;
        List<MyData> list;
        public MyDataAdapter(Activity _context, List<MyData> _list)
        {
            context = _context;
            list = _list;
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;

            // re-use an existing view, if one is available
            // otherwise create a new one
            if (view == null)
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Grid, parent, false);

            //find GridView from Grid.axml and set columns count to 2 (only ID and Nick)
            GridLayout tableView = view.FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.gridLayout1);
            tableView.ColumnCount = 2;

            //Creating TextView to show ID, place position is 0 - first
            TextView textCaption = new TextView(view.Context);
            textCaption.SetText(list[position].ID.ToString(), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            tableView.AddView(textCaption, 0);

            //Creating TextView to show ID, place position is 1 - second in a row of Grid
            textCaption = new TextView(view.Context);
            textCaption.SetText(list[position].Nick, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            tableView.AddView(textCaption, 1);

            return view;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return list.Count; }
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override MyData this[int index]
        {
            get { return list[index]; }
        }            
    }
```

All of this should show to end-user two rows of ListView. First row contains GridView with two TextView elements "1" and "Nick#1" in one row. Second row should contains GridView with "2" and "Nick#2" in one row like this:
[calling from MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP2ki.jpg)

...but instead each of 2 ListView rows contains a lot of GridView rows with data:
[calling from Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXmiY.jpg)

If you will disable Tab by commenting

```
        //ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        //AddTab("Tab 1", new SampleTabFragment1());
```

and uncommenting area of code from MainActivity.cs

```
//to test if Adapter works properly without Fragment
```

it will show correct result using exactly the same Custom Adapter and Layouts structure as it was used from Fragment **SampleTabFragment1()** call.
Look like there are some tricks about using Fragments with custom Adapter and\or layouts, what do you think?

Comment: I think you might want to take another look at the design philosophy of fragments - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html It seems like you might be "nesting" layouts in which your expected list is being added multiple times. Simplify your layouts to ensure that you have a simple `FrameLayout` that you are plugging your fragment into. You should then set breakpoints on your `list.Count` and ensuring it only has 2 items. Then check to see if other controls are being populated as well.

Comment: But it's already simplified as much as possible: Main Layout contains FragmentContainer for Fragment. Layout for Fragment is very simple - just ListView. That's it. Grid Layout is only using for custom list adapter which works pretty well. The problem is list.Count property is ok and ==2. But it's calling few times from Fragment for some reason and it's not correct. And it's calling correct if use from MainActivity instead of Fragment.

Comment: I prefer using `FragmentTransaction.Replace()` as adding and removing fragments can sometimes be error prone unless you understand the lifecycle. Try to refactor that code to a `Replace()` instead!

Comment: Looks like problem is how `ListView` recycling mechanism works. Here [some info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works) But in my case I can't even use `match_parent` for `layout_height` of `ListView`. Instead should use fixed value.
Anyway, it's not a solution to use fixed size since all my data is dynamic and It's not good idea to use fixed size at all. Look like need to take a look at ArrayAdapter Android implementation and try to understand "magic" why it works fine for Fragment (if size isn't fixed) and why all custom Adapters doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After facing this problem I decided to switch to Java Android instead of using C#. In a few weeks after learning Java (and Android development) I tried to rewrite my program and faced the same problem! This time I've tried to dynamically create `TableRows` with `TextViews` inside it, via my custom adapter for `ListView`.

Still got duplicated elements in first row! But solution is very easy. You should create new Views during runtime **only** if current `view` for adapter wasn't created (equals null). (*Of course, if you don't create any Views dynamically, instead use from XML layout it already works fine*) This solution works just fine for my Java program and it should be like this for my old C# code:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;

    // re-use an existing view, if one is available
    // otherwise create a new one
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Grid, parent, false);
        //find GridView from Grid.axml and set columns count to 2 (only ID and Nick)
        GridLayout tableView = view.FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.gridLayout1);
        tableView.ColumnCount = 2;

        //Creating TextView to show ID, place position is 0 - first
        TextView textCaption = new TextView(view.Context);
        textCaption.SetText(list[position].ID.ToString(), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        tableView.AddView(textCaption, 0);

        //Creating TextView to show ID, place position is 1 - second in a row of Grid
        textCaption = new TextView(view.Context);
        textCaption.SetText(list[position].Nick, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        tableView.AddView(textCaption, 1);
    }

    return view;
}
```